Configuring SSL Trusted Custom CAs in Neo4J Desktop Client
I have disabled HTTP/HTTPS access within my Neo4j server instance and am only allowing connections through bolt. My bolt connector config can be seen below:
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=REQUIRED
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:8080
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=:8080

I still want to be able to visualize my data through the Neo4j Desktop client on Windows.  When I try to connect to the Remote DBMS I get an error stating that the remote DBMS is unreachable with the specified configuration.  I can connect from the same machine via the Python library but not through the desktop client.  With the Python library I have to specify the paths to the certificates to trust using the neo4j.TrustCustomCAs class when initializing the driver.  Example:
self.driver = neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver(
        host,
        auth=(username, password),
        trusted_certificates=neo4j.TrustCustomCAs(
            str(CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY) + cert_chain_path,
            str(CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY) + cert_intermediate_path,
            str(CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY) + cert_root_path,
        ),
        encrypted=True,
    )

Is there a way to point to these trusted CAs using the desktop client?  I believe this is the root of the error I am seeing, though I could be wrong.  The logs did not have anything in them with regards to the error so I am just going out on a limb here.

Did you ruled the powershell prerequisite mentioned in the troubleshooting guide for windows?

I don't think that guide is relevant to the SSL config in the Neo4j client.

When the hostname part is not specified, the listen_address is configured as 127.0.0.1:8080. This restricts the connections to the localmachine. I tried the same locally and couldn't connect until I updated the listen and advertised address to 0.0.0.0:8080 .  Are you running your server in a VPN?
